# Undetermined Coefficients for solving non homogeneous equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes

I can't seem to figure out where I am going wrong in my steps. I checked the answer and it is different.

The question is:

$$y'' + 2y' - 3y = 3te^t$$

The roots are: -3,1.
Thus the general solution is:
$$y=C_1e^{-3t} + C_2e^t$$

The particular solution i am going with is:
$$y_p = Ate^t$$
$$y'_p = Ae^t + Ate^t$$
$$y''_p = 2Ae^t + Ate^t$$

Therefore:
$$2Ae^t + Ate^t + 2Ae^t + 2Ate^t - 3Ate^t = 3te^t$$

$$4Ae^t = 3te^t$$

Then solving for A:
$$4A=3$$
$$A=3/4$$

Thus, $y_p = \frac{3}{4}(e^t + te^t)$

Then the general solution would be:
$y = C_1e^{-3t} + C_2e^t  + \frac{3}{4}(e^t + te^t)$

Any guidance with my mistake would be greatly appreciated. As an aside, what does it mean when a question asks to use the stability
result to determine they will have a globally stable solution of the above question. Thank you.

Comment: Be carefull with your variable sometimes you use t sometimes you use x...

Comment: Thank you. I must've done it accidentally.

Comment: yw Safder...I know it's just a typo..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your particular solution is not correct. Note that $4Ae^t = 3te^t$ does not imply that $A=3/4$. Moreover, what is $C$?

In the characteristic polynomial, the multiplicity of the root ${\bf 1}$ is $m=1$ . Therefore, since $f(t)=te^{{\bf1}\cdot t}$, it follows that the particular solution should have the form
$$y_p=t^m(At+B)e^{{\bf1}\cdot t}=(At^2+Bt)e^t$$
where $A$ and $B$ are real constants to be found. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes I can. I had a feeling it was the particular solution. Would you happen to know how to check for global stability? Thank you.

Comment: What is the definition of "global stability" in your book/course?

Comment: This what the notes say, i'm a little confused by it. Consider a homogenous equation equation $y'' + ay' + by = f(t)$. Then the solution is in the form $y=y_h + y_s$, where $y_h, y_s$ are the homogenous and non-homogenous solutions respectively.  $t \rightarrow \infty$, $ y = y_s$ if and only if a>0, b>0. Thus y_s is only globally stable if and only if a>0 and b>0 if and only if the real parts of the roots  of the characteristic equation are both negative. Would you be able clarify the requirements for stability for me?

Comment: In your opinion, in this case, is $y$ globally stable?

Comment: Seeing as though b is negative, and one of the roots is positive. It is not globally stable.

Comment: I agree with you.

Comment: A quick question about finding the multiplicity. Which multiplicity do you choose from? I know both -3 and 1 have multiplicity 1. Is there a reason you specified the root 1 over -3?

Comment: Yes,  see the coeeficient 1 in the exponential of $ f $.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79207/discussion-between-safder-and-robert-z).

Answer (score 1):

The particular solution should be:
$$y_p=(At^2+Bt)e^t \implies y'_p=(At^2+(2A+B)t+B)e^t$$

***Better approach***

Substitute $y=ze^t$ The equation becomes
$$z''+4z'=3t$$
Use the variation of constant now $(y_p=at^2+bt)$..It looks easier..

***Another approach***

$$y'' + 2y' - 3y = 3te^t$$
$$(y''-y')+3(y'-y)=3te^t$$
$$(y'e^{-t})'+3(ye^{-t})'=3t$$
$$(y'e^{-t})+3(ye^{-t})=\frac 32t^2+K_1$$
$$(y'e^{3t})+3(ye^{3t})=(\frac 32t^2+K_1)e^{4t}$$
$$(ye^{3t})'=(\frac 32t^2+K_1)e^{4t}$$
$$ye^{3t}=\int (\frac 32t^2+K_1)e^{4t}dt$$
$$y(t)=K_2e^{-3t}+K_1e^t+\frac 32e^{-3t}\int t^2e^{4t}dt$$
Finally
$$\boxed{y(t)=K_2e^{-3t}+K_1e^t+\frac 38e^tt^2-\frac 3{16}e^tt}$$
where
$$
\begin{cases}
\displaystyle y_p=\frac 38e^tt(t-\frac 1{2}) \\
\displaystyle y_h=K_2e^{-3t}+K_1e^t
\end{cases}
$$